# Polymerisation of a UV-curing resin

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, polymers

I have a [photosensitive resin MSDS](http://www.esun3d.net/UploadFiles/Download/MSDS_eSUN_LCD%20eResin-PLA.pdf). It lists a mixture of [1,6-Hexanediol diacrylate](https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/rn/13048-33-4) ($\ce{C_{12}H_{18}O_4}$) with its proper CAS number and [Polyurethane acrylate](https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/rn/25035-69-2) together with the CAS number of "Butyl acrylate/methyl methacrylate/methacrylic acid copolymer" with the formula (or rather, formulas) of $\ce{(C7H_{12}O2.C5H8O2.C4H6O2)_x}$. There's also the Photoinitiator [1-Hydroxycyclohexyl phenyl ketone](https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/rn/947-19-3) listed. The additives of color and reaction inhibitor are most likely irrelevant for the actual question, so I leave them out.

My organic chemistry is somewhat rusty, but the first part of the compound I can identify as having the setup $\ce{H2C=CH-CO-O-C6H12-O-CO-CH=CH2}$. This appears to be a quite nice molecule that reacts evenly on both sides under polymerization. This material is also listed as photosensitive, which I interpret that it sheds something from both ends to *activate* the ends.

The other, of course is a mixture of three monomers: Butyl acrylate ($\ce{H2C=CH-CO-O-C4H9}$), methyl methacrylate ($\ce{H2C=C(CH3)-CO-O-CH3}$) and methacrylic acid ($\ce{H2C=C(CH3)-COOH}$). The first two have ester groups in them, the last has its precursor, the $\ce{-COOH}$ group (carboxylic acid). All these only seem to have one *active* side to me.

Assuming the four main chemicals are mixed somewhat evenly and in even numbers and what might be an ample supply of the *starter* Hydroxycyclohexyl-phenyl-ketone, they surely will react and polymerize under UV light of about 400 nm (+- 5), as this is how the mixture behaves in its native application, an SLA printer.

However I have a problem with these parts:

- What kind of reaction does happen between the compounds? I remember vaguely that some polymerizations create *waste* in the shape of water (was that condensation?), but I don't really see that happening here for most of the combinations and, as a result, I fail to see what the parts of the polymer might look like in their bonded state.
- What type of bonds does the resulting polymer have? This is pretty much the direct result of failing to see the reaction between the compounds. I thought I had seen a possibility to form an ester ($\ce{R_1-CO-O-R_2}$) between the methacrylic acid and the hexanediol diacrylate, but then realized the later misses an alcohol group ($\ce{R-OH}$) to attack and create water from to form the bond. So I am pretty sure that these don't bond as esters to one another, but what is the correct name for these bonds that elude me?!
- What would this polymer be classed as? I remember that some polymers are classed based on their monomers, manufacturing process, the chain length, bond type, and the macro-structure, putting each into several groups. These would allowing to estimate some vague properties about them. It's most certainly not a Homogenous one like pure PolyLacticAcid, as it is basically made up of 4 different monomers. It also should not form an elastic bond due to what I know from the MSDS and that the processed resin is a somewhat brittle product. But what groups it can be put into from the polymerization process?

Comment: You need a photoinitiator to do this. Related article: Songklanakarin J. Sci. Technol. 2011, 33(2), 201-207 (http://www.thaiscience.info/Journals/Article/SONG/10761807.pdf).

Comment: that would be, according to the MSDS, CAS 947-19-3, so... 1-Hydroxycyclohexyl phenyl ketone

Comment: That'd work. Check with photo-curing coating. Similar reactanets and polymerization.

Comment: in this case, it's an SLA resin, I think the chemistry might be quite similar.

Comment: I don't get it. It's just an acrylic resin and you get polyacrylate!

Comment: @Mithoron I beg your pardon, but the last time I had had my fingers on working out any polymerization was 13 years ago.

Comment: :/ While most of your post is nice and reasoning OK, the questions in the end are not stated well. You need to write them much more precisely.

Comment: @Mithoron I hope by adding more to explain how and where I fail to see the process might help to give it at least some of the precision you ask for.

Comment: Yeah, that's better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymerizations expelling water, equally known as [polycondensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_polymer) ([PET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene_terephthalate) is a typical product), are a subset of polymerizations. The **radical polymerization** here is more likely to proceed differently with three reaction types running concurrently: initiation, propagation, and termination.

- During the **initiation**, light splits the phenylketone into two fragments with one unpaired electron each. This is symbolized by the dot next to the oxygen atoms, denoting that these chemicals are radicals:

  [image]
- These radicals may react with one electron of the double bond of a neutral acrylate in the **propagation** reaction. Symbolized by blue is the newly formed single bond between the two reagents (first line).  Simultaneously, the other electron of the former double bond represents a new site where again a neutral acrylate may react (second line).  This growth of the polymer chain may continue again and again, or propagate (third line).

  [image]
- As soon as there are radicals formed, there may be a number of reactions where these carbon-centered radicals are consumed.  This cancels the further growth of the polymer chains.  Among these **termination** reactions, hydrogen-transfer / redox reactions as well as dimerizations are the most prominent ones.  Some which seem likely to occur are depicted below:

  [image]

## Structure

Your starting material consists of a starter, and a blend of bifunctional acrylates.  Thus the curation will yield polymer chains that are cross-linked with each other.  The illustration below (for a different material) symbolized this by the blue zig-zag lines:

[image]

(Konuray *et al.*, *Polymers* **2018**, *10*, 178 [doi 10.3390/polym10020178](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4360/10/2/178), open access)

Because you started with multiple different monomers, it would be an example of **branched [copolymers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copolymer)**.